# Are faceplates for different shimano brifters compatible?

Tags: brakes, gears, shimano

I got a used [brifter](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/6918#6918) and the faceplate fell off. I am pretty sure it was a 105. It works well enough but it looks shitty.

Does anyone know if I can just order whichever shimano brifter faceplate, and it will fit? If that was the case, I might just get one to match my other brifter (a tiagra, I think).

Comment: Talking about things like this oviously:
http://www.amazon.com/Shimano-ST-5600-Plate-Fixing-Screw/dp/B001GSMHEM

Comment: For anyone wondering what a brifter is, it's a combination between brake and shifter. I mention this since I had to look it up.

Comment: Judging by the answers here, they aren't a standard interface. I think I'll ask at an LBS.

http://www.bikeforums.net/archive/index.php/t-381146.html

Comment: It might be worth adding brakes and shifter tags, and perhaps tweaking the title to say brifters (brakes and shifters) because you are't getting too many views yet.  That could be simply timing or it could be because people don't recognise the term.  I think the actual interface is fairly common these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

No they are not. Each model, and usually each year requires a specific face plate.